# change when computer sleeps

Tags: windows-7

How to change the Window 7 sleeps option 
Can't find the setting on control panel. my computer keep going to sleep after half an hour

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. I think it would be better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to open Control Panel -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings (beside your selected plan) -> Change advanced power settings (under "Put the computer to sleep")

This Advanced settings window will give you all the options available.  Click on the + sign beside "Sleep" and then the plus sign beside "Sleep after".  You can set it to Never or some time in minutes.

Note that if you're not an administrator on your system then you may not be able to alter some of these settings, and they'll be greyed out to indicate that.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I could find "sleep after" option as well under the advance power settings. under sleep there only got allow wake up time, nothing else. cheers

Comment: That being the case, if it's an older board then it may not support sleep mode; I have an old system that has this problem.  I would need the model in order to find out.  Also, it could be that the drivers for your chipset aren't fully installed.  If you can provide computer type or model of motherboard then I can look into it more, or you can just take these ideas as a jumping point.